# Exception: You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps-script-api

Issue: Receiving error when running google app script in google sheets: "Exception: You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later."

I have a google apps script that integrates with google calendar. It creates an event when a row to the spreadsheet is added. If anything within that row is edited, it updates the original event (tied to the same event ID).

Help would be greatly apprecaited.

```
function exportEvents() {
  var space = " - "
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "ID";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[5]);  // Scheduled  Publication Date
    var numb = row[2];
    var title = numb +space+ row[0];
    var loc = row[3];
    var desc = "Content 1: "+row[1] +"\n" +
               "\nContent 2 "+row[6]+ "\n" +
               "\nContent 3: "+row[9]+"\n" +
               "\nContent 4: "+row[7]+"\n" + 
               "\nContent 5 (If Drafted): "+row[4]+"\n" +
               "\nRunning List"
               
                  //Further code can be added to allow for additional records
    var id = row[8];              // eventId Hidden
        // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
    }
    if (!event) {
      //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {location:loc}).getId();
      row[9] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(title);
      event.setLocation(loc);
      event.setDescription(desc);
      // event.setTime(tstart, tstop); // cannot setTime on eventSeries.
      // ... but we CAN set recurrence!
      var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
      event.setRecurrence(recurrence, date);
    }

  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
 
}
```

Comment: When you want to create a lot of events in a Google Calendar, how about using the batch request? So, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65802629

Comment: How many times is the spreadsheet updated in a day? The [create events quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) states that for a free gmail you have 5000 calendar events per day. Are you surpassing that or are you creating multiple events at once?